# Prove that the electrostatic potential is zero (Wald)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential

Let $V$ be a bounded region of space and let $\phi $ be an electrostatic potential that is source free in this region, so that $\nabla^2 \phi=0$ throughout $V$. Suppose that $x$ is lying on the boundary $S=\partial V$, we have $\phi(x)=-f(x)\hat{n} \cdot \nabla \phi(x)$ where $f$ is a non-negative function $(f(x)\geq 0)$ and $\hat{n}$ is the outward pointing normal. Show that $\phi =0$ throughout $V$.

I'm reviewing EM and I was sad to see I couldn't do the first problem, I'm looking for hints.

Comment: Hint: “integrate by parts” and use the divergence theorem on the integral $\int_{\mathcal{V}}\|\nabla\phi\|^2\,dV$. Also you should be more precise in the statement: that equation holds for **all** points $x\in S$; the way you worded it makes it sound like it’s only at a particular point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Stokes' theorem
$$
  \int (\nabla\phi)^2 d{\rm vol} + \int \phi \nabla^2\phi d{\rm vol} \\
=\int_{\partial V} \phi [({\bf n}\cdot \nabla) \phi] d|S|\\= -\int \phi^2 (1/f)d|S|.
$$
The first term is positive unless $\phi$ is a constant and the second term is zero. The final expression   is negative if   $\phi^2(1/f) $ is anywhere non zero on the boundary. So the only cosnistent possibility is  $\phi$ is everywhere zero on the boundary and $|\nabla \phi|=0$. But  then $\phi$ constant and zero on the boundary, and so is everywhere zero.

Comment: I would reword slightly to avoid division by zero with $f$: $\int_V|\nabla\phi|^2\,dV=\int_{S}\phi\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial n}\,dS=-\int_{S}f\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial n}\right)^2\,dS$. The integral on the LHS is $\geq 0$, while on the RHS we have $\leq 0$, so both integrals vanish and since their integrands are non-negative, they both vanish (everywhere by continuity).

Comment: @peek-a-boo. Yes, Nice observation!